# How to add header to legend in qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I would like to add a header to the legend when exporting a qgis project to a web map using the qgis2web plugin. The text above the list of available layers. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**One-time change :**

After the export you need to edit the `index.html` file contained in the export folder

Before closing the `</head>` section you must insert this `<style>`, which you can customize to your liking (For example if the title is long it will go on two lines and therefore it will have to increase the `margin-top` of the `.layer-switcher ul` element so that it does not overlap)

```css
    <style>
        .layerswitcher-title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        height: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display:none;
        }
        .layer-switcher.shown .layerswitcher-title {
        display:block!important;
        }
        .layer-switcher ul {
        margin-top: 30px;
        }
    </style>
```

You will also need to add this script before closing the `</body>` section, personalize it with your title

```js
    <script>
        // Select "layer-switcher" element
        var layerSwitcher = document.querySelector('.layer-switcher');
    
        // Create <a> element
        var linkItem = document.createElement('a');
        linkItem.textContent = 'Layerswitcher Title Example';
    
        // Add class
        linkItem.classList.add('layerswitcher-title');
    
        // Add <a> element like first child
        layerSwitcher.insertBefore(linkItem, layerSwitcher.firstChild);
    </script>
```

**Always edit :**

If you want to set a default title without having to edit the index.html file every time after exporting, you will need to edit the `full-screen.html` or `canvas-size.html` file (depending on your export type) contained in this path    `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis2web\templates`

But be careful !!! with each update of qgis2web these files will be overwritten.